# Group Array Items with similar strings

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have a simple array of strings:

```
$Hand = array("05h", "02h", "03c", "02s", "04h");
```

Here's what I want to do with it:

If a number appears more than once, then group that number at the beginning of the array. So my end result would be:

```
$Hand = array("02h", "02s", "05h", "03c", "04h");
```

Here's what I've pieced together so far from other answers, but I don't know how to make the pieces work together to accomplish my goal.

```
$Hand = array("05h", "02h", "03c", "02s", "04h");

rsort($Hand,SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r ($Hand);

echo "<br>";

function myfunction($Card)
{
 return(substr($Card,0,2));
}

$CountedHand = array_count_values(array_map("myfunction",$Hand));
asort($CountedHand);
print_r(array_reverse($CountedHand));
```

Uchiha's comment solved the original array, but I have a couple more complex arrays that it doesn't work well for. Here's a couple other arrays.

```
$Hand2 = array("05h", "02h", "03c", "02s", "03h");
$Hand3 = array("03s", "02h", "03c", "02s", "03h");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use asort() for the result:

```
    <?php
    $Hand = array("05h", "02h", "03c", "02s", "04h");
    asort($Hand);
    print_r($Hand);
     ?>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This does sort them, but I need the duplicates placed at the beginning of the Array. I'm not simply looking for a sorted array. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you but it doesn't output as of your expected output. You can simply use `usort` function

```
usort($Hand, function($a,$b) {
    if((int) $a == (int) $b){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Output PHP >= 5.5.0 - 5.6.22:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 02s
    [1] => 02h
    [2] => 05h
    [3] => 03c
    [4] => 04h
)
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/gCfIJ)

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. I tried clicking the Up vote, but nothing happened. Anyway, it works for the one scenario I provided above, but I've added a couple other scenarios that it doesn't sort properly. This does give me something to work with though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First get the frequency of each word in the array and then sort array like below

```
$hand2 = array("05h", "02h", "03c", "02h", "03h");
$freq = array_count_values($hand2);
arsort($freq);
print_r($freq);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that just creates a new array of the number of times each item appears.